# Filter image as per product type in file upload jquery plugin with asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, filter, tablesorter, jquery-file-upload

Here is the scenario I used the plugin https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload for multiple file upload But I need the images loaded as per product type as you can see attached image. When I select the product type from the drop down then it will display the images that product types only. How can I achieve this wit the help of above plugin.

[image]

Comment: I don't know if your file upload plugin can do it, but it would surprise me : table filter/sorter problematic is quite far from uploading file one's, so you should look for table sorter plugins.

Comment: Thanks @Fractaliste but I don't want the table sorter I just wanted the filter as per the product type.

Comment: Oh of course, I would say a *table filter plugin*

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the plugin does but this answer to me seems like it could be a purely JQuery answer. Unless I misunderstood the question.

I would be temped to first check what the drop down has been set to. So `var x = $("#dropdownName").val();` where `x` is equal to the values set in html `value=""` propery. So let's say that...

```
<select id="dropdownName">
    <option value="productType1">Product Type 1</option>
    <option value="productType2">Product Type 2</option>
    <option value="productType3">Product Type 3</option>
</select>
```

that way when I push upload, the current product type now is set for what was uploaded and I am given a value set that DOES NOT have anything to do with the plugin. That being said, for all I know the plugin has this stuff built in and there is a better way but since I am unfamiliar with this plugin it seems JQuery alone could be a plausible answer.

Once I know what type of product is being uploaded i.e. `product type 1`, I can use an extra table in my database to store this information (unless one exists already that can have an extra row or two added without errors/problems). So perhaps add it to a prod_type lookup table who's entire job is to store the unique identifier of the product type as well as the unique identifier of the image uploaded. I'm assuming there would be an images table with id, path, extension, etc... thats why I suggested this.

So, once I click upload, my own lookup table keeps track of what product type each image belongs to.

Then, now that I know which type each product belongs to it should be really easy to do some simple querying maybe even a stored procedure or two since this would be a static querying situation. When you now go to view a page or load a page with only a certain type of product type in it you can simply query your database for only the product type 1 or 2 or whatever and from a simple join on the prod_type lookup table and the images table you could easily see which images belong in this section, then populate it.

I have no way of knowing what type of DBAS your using so SQL would be senseless to type out here however this could be the JQuery code handling the AJAX request/response for this updated product listing.

`Request:`

```
$.post("fileToQueryDBASForProdType.php", {prodType: $("#dropdownName").val()}, function(data) {

    //Response Handler Callback
    //This is where you would begin to handle the data variable returned in completion
    //Usually the data var in this case would be a built HTML set made inside the .php called
    //Most cases its as simple as ....

   $(".foundResultsSection").innerHTML(data);

});
```